# SAS PROC PRINT is really slow for me, any ideas?

Tags: sas

Let me start by saying that I'm on a team that are all very new to SAS.  We are using Enterprise Guide 5.1 in SAS 9.3, and have a set of schedule data arranged vertically (one or two rows per person per day).  We have some `PROC SQL` statements, a `PROC TRANSPOSE`, and a couple other steps that together primarily make the data grouped by week and displayed horizontally.  That set of code works fine.  The first time the process flow runs, it takes a little extra time establishing the connection to the database, but once the connection is made, the rest of the process only takes a few seconds (about 6 seconds for a test run of 7 months of data: 58,000 rows and 26 columns of source data going to 6,000 rows, 53 columns of output).

Our problem is in the output.  The end-users are looking for results in Excel, so we are using the SAS Excel add-in and opening a stored process.  In order to get output, we need a `PROC PRINT`, or something similar.  But using `PROC PRINT` on the results from above (6,000 rows x 53 columns) is taking 36 seconds just to generate.  Then, it is taking another 10 seconds or so to render in EG, and even more time in Excel.

The code is very basic, just:

```
PROC PRINT DATA=WORK.Report_1
    NOOBS
    LABEL;
RUN;
```

We have also tried using a basic `PROC REPORT`, but we are only gaining 3 seconds: it is still taking 33 seconds to generate plus rendering time.

```
PROC REPORT DATA=WORK.Report_1
    RUN;
QUIT;
```

Any ideas why it is taking so long?  Are there other print options that might be faster?

Comment: How long does it take to PROC PRINT to an HTML file (or just to the normal results destination-of-your-choice), not using the Excel add in?

Comment: That helped a little, but still 28 seconds.

Comment: Where is your work library located?  Is it local to the server or sitting on a file share somewhere? `%put %sysfunc(pathname(work));` will print the path to the current work library.  I have only ever seen issues like this when the temp space is on a slow file system.

Comment: @EvilBob22 - It wasn't intended to help that way, it was a test to see if excel was the problem.  It's not - so it's probably something related to your datasets (like DomPazz is pointing to).  `PROC PRINT` should not take very long in and of itself.

Comment: @Joe Good, I didn't think `PROC PRINT` should take that long.

Comment: @DomPazz I don't have access to the server itself, but the work path is showing as the e: drive on that system.  I'll bug the systems team to find out how much space is available there.

Comment: I'd think data steps would be slow also if it's just work library, honestly; more likely you have an issue with where the data's going - or a configuration issue somewhere.  Do you have EG set to automatically download results?

Comment: Yeah, that drive is 200 GB, so it is pretty unlikely.  @Joe, I'm not sure, is that "Automatically open data or results when generated"?, that is on.

Comment: I can replicate the time issue in PROC PRINT locally.  See proposed solution below.  I use this for sending large results to Excel regularly.

Comment: I don't see how size of drive is particularly important - it's not that it might be filling up, but if it's slow and/or across a network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on my laptop.  Took about 13 seconds to output a table with 6000 records and 53 variables (I used 8 character long strings) with PROC PRINT and ODS HTML.

```
data test;
format vars1-vars53 $8.;
array vars[53];
do i=1 to 6000;
    do j=1 to 53;
        vars[j] = "aasdfjkl;";
    end;
    output;
end;    
drop i j;
run;

ods html body="c:\temp\test.html";
proc print data=test noobs;
run;
ods html close;
```

File size was a little less than 11M.

If you are only using this as a stored process, you can make it a streaming process and write to _WEBOUT HTML.  This will work for viewing in Excel and greatly reduces the size of the HTML generated (no CSS included).

```
data _null_;
set test end=last;
file _webout;
array vars[53] $;
format outstr $32.;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    put '<html><body><table>';
    put '<tr>';
    do i=1 to 53;
        outstr = vname(vars[i]);
        put '<th>' outstr '</th>';
    end;
    put '</tr>';
end;

put '<tr>';
do i=1 to 53;
    put '<td>' vars[i] '</td>';
end;
put '</tr>';

if last then do;
    put '</table></body></html>';
end;
run;
```

This takes .2 seconds to run and generated 6M of output.  Add any HTML decorators as needed.

Comment: This is looking very promising.  We have a variable number of columns, so I'm going to have to do some messing around with the table's metadata to get it working right.  The initial testing leveraging this code goes from reading data, to manipulations, to printing 6,000 blank rows in Excel in 51 seconds.  (The `PROC PRINT` version was taking 4 minutes or more.)